# Removing trailing empty values from an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

How to remove the trailing empty and nil values from an array in Ruby.

The "Compact" function is not fullfil my requirement. It is removing all the 'nil' values from an array. But I want to remove the trailing empty and nil values alone.
Please give me any suggestion on this..

Comment: What's causing you to have trailing empty and nil values in an array? Is it the result of splitting a string?

Answer (score 10):

This will do it and should be fine if you only have a couple trailing `nil`s and empty strings:

```
a.pop while a.last.to_s.empty?
```

For example:

```
>> a = ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?", nil, '', nil, nil]
=> ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?", nil, "", nil, nil]
>> a.pop while a.last.to_s.empty?
=> nil
>> a
=> ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?"]
```

The `.to_s.empty?` bit is just a quick'n'dirty way to cast `nil` to an empty string so that both `nil` and `''` can be handled with a single condition.

Another approach is to scan the array backwards for the first thing you don't want to cut off:

```
n = a.length.downto(0).find { |i| !a[i].nil? && !a[i].empty? }
a.slice!(n + 1, a.length - n - 1) if(n && n != a.length - 1)
```

For example:

```
>> a = ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?", nil, '', nil, nil]
=> ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?", nil, "", nil, nil]
>> n = a.length.downto(0).find { |i| !a[i].nil? && !a[i].empty? }
=> 5
>> a.slice!(n + 1, a.length - n - 1) if(n && n != a.length - 1)
=> [nil, "", nil, nil]
>> a
=> ["where", "is", nil, "pancakes", nil, "house?"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
['a', "", nil].compact.reject(&:empty?) => ["a"]
```

Comment: Downvote. You are not removing **tailing** empty and nil values this way

Comment: Correct, I wonder how I could miss that part of the question.